# Enter multiple directories, enter subdirectories, and move all files up one directory with bash

Tags: r, bash

I have multiple directories like:

```
T1_5356
T1_5357
T1_5358
.
.
```

Each directory has a sub-directory called `DTI`

I would like to enter each directory and copy the contents of its respective DTI contents up one directory (so `cp T1_5356/DTI/* ../`)

I have been trying variations of:

```
for dir in T1*; do cd $dir; cp -r DTI/*; cd ../; done
```

but I get an error:
`` cp: cannot stat `DTI/*': No such file or directory ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from inside the directory that contains all the T1_* directories:

```
for dir in T1_*; do cp $dir/DTI/* $dir; done
```